# How do I delete records in a dependent table from within VB/C# EF code?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

VS2013 update 4, VB (or C#), EF 6.0, SQL, LINQ

This is a difficult question for me to ask in a clear manner because I'm uncertain of the proper terms to use.  The sum of it is my code deletes items in a record, but sets the pointer in the secondary table to NULL instead of deleting the record there.  The following is a simple representation of my model and code.

```
Public Class DbContext
  Public Property records As DbSet(Of record)
End Class

Public Class record
  Public Property recordID As Integer
  Public Property DataItems As New List(Of DataItem)
End Class

Public Class DataItem
  Public Property DataItemID As Integer
  Public Property Data As Integer
End Class
```

If I execute code using a .Remove() each record in records will end up with 0 DataItems (I can see that in VS debug mode) but the DataItem table is still full of records, all with NULL pointers.  **(This paragraph changed after initial post & incorrect code that was referred to in a comment was removed)**

I understand that I could add the following to the Public Class DbContext:

```
Public Property DataItems As DbSet(Of DataItem)
```

Then I could go through and remove all DataItems that have the NULL pointer, but this doesn't seem like the way it's supposed to be done, so I'm asking for help to understand how I should be coding in this situation.

Is there a proper way in LINQ to remove a record from a List such that the actual record is also removed instead of merely having the pointer set to NULL?

Comment: You actually did not delete any record, what you delete is the `DataItems` from each record. Also it's surprising that the `For Each` loop does not throw any exception because you try to modify a collection while looping through it (at least in c# that would throw an exception). If you want to clear all records, why not try the `Remove` or `RemoveRange` method? To clear all records, try this `db.records.RemoveRange(db.records)`

Comment: Actually, not so surprising - I copied the wrong code into the post!! Yes, that code threw an exception as expected.  But after I rewrote it properly it still did not delete the records.  I will try your suggestion right now.

Comment: @Hopeless. Your .RemoveRange() solution was the correct answer for me.  I will follow-up with some additional comments after some more testing, but you might want to put your comment into an answer I can mark as the answer.

Comment: While the solution to delete the records that have NULL in the return pointer works great, I still have the question remaining about deleting the records in the secondary, or child table, in this case the DataItems table (meaning the dbset).  Is it the case that these have to be 'manually' deleted after removing the DataItems from within the individual Records?  If so, why is that?  Stated differently, why doesn't deleting a DataItem from the List(Of DataItem) within a Record also remove the row from the DataItems table?  Thx.

Comment: It depends on how you design your database. I'm not sure if there is any relationship made (as well as the actual database tables you have). About the child-parent relationship, if deleting parents, you have to manually delete the children first unless you set up the relationship to cascade the deletion. With that cascading, the children will be automatically deleted when their parents are deleted. LinqToEntity won't take care of relationship when deleting, you should set up a correct relationship as I said.

Comment: I have other db designs where I manually handle child deletion for a purpose.  I guess this is the first time I wanted child deletion to cascade automatically so I've never coded it.  Based on your comment I researched a variety of posts WRT cascading deletes; some say set it up in SSMS, others in code -   I saw a reference to a .mapping command but haven't ever used that.  Which is the currently recommended technique for EF6+ to setup automatic cascading deletes whether or not the entity is in memory or not? Thx.  BTW, did you want to write your solution(s) as an answer?

Comment: In fact what I commented is fairly least for an answer. It's unfortunate that I'm not very experienced in EF6 and have done only cascading via database management system. So you should try asking another question about that problem, maybe some EF6 experts could help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87607/discussion-between-alan-and-hopeless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer for others who have the same question, the comments above provide the solution that worked for me.  I had to manually delete the children, and in other cases create a method to search for and delete records with NULL in the return pointer.  The suggestion to use RemoveRange() worked well.  While setting up the cascade delete seems a good solution, I didn't want to manually set that up in SSMS, so I do the manual deletions for now until someone can explain how to set this up in EF from the model definition.